# sp_help with different object types with the same name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a table with the same name as a user-defined data type (UDDT), and when I use `sp_help`, only the table definition is shown.

Is there a way to use `sp_help` or an equivalent to show the definition for the UDDT instead?

`sp_help` only appears to have an `@ObjName` parameter, with no way to specify I actually want information about a type.

This script demonstrates the ability to create a table and a user-defined data type with the same name and under the same schema:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Address] FROM [nvarchar](40) NULL;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address]
(
    [AddressID] Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have two objects with the same name, it is almost certain that one is in a different schema. So to differentiate, you need to include the schema name in the call to `sp_help` as well.

```
EXEC sys.sp_help N'dbo.tablename';
EXEC sys.sp_help N'otherschema.udtname';
```

You should always be using schema-qualified object names anyway:

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

And in the case where you managed to create a table and a UDDT with the same name under the same schema:

1. I believe this is a bug in the engine. It should not allow me to create a data type and an object with the same name under the same schema. And I don't know why you would want to do that, even though it is allowed.
2. `sp_help` is certainly not prepared for that (and I don't see any chance for their investment in fixing it, especially if 1. is correct). It will return the information for the table, but not the type. [The documentation mentions nothing of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms187335(v=sql.110)), of course - so at the very least there is information missing in the docs, and perhaps you could also consider this a feature gap (`sp_help` *could* take type as an argument, but again, don't hold your breath).

So your options in the meantime are:

1. Rename the type.
2. Don't expect to use `sp_help` to get information about the type.
3. Write your own version of `sp_help`.

`sp_help` has the following basic logic, which you could change to include both:

```
-- @objname must be either sysobjects or systypes: first look in sysobjects
....
-- IF NOT IN SYSOBJECTS, TRY SYSTYPES --
....
    -- UNDONE: SHOULD CHECK FOR AND DISALLOW MULTI-PART NAME
....
    -- IF NOT IN SYSTYPES, GIVE UP
```

Or you could add a parameter that lets you decide which object class is more important.

Of course you need to fix any line that uses `TypePropertyEx()`, an undocumented system function, to do this instead:

```
--'Prec'  = Convert(int,TypePropertyEx(user_type_id, 'precision')),
[Prec] = [precision],
--'Scale' = Convert(int,TypePropertyEx(user_type_id, 'scale')),
[Scale] = [scale],
....
FROM sys.types
...
```

*Why they use `TypePropertyEx()` here, I don't have a clue.*

But, in all honesty, the best solution is to **rename your type**. Who knows what other conflicts you'll come across.

Comment: Many thanks Aaron. Now need to talk to our developers to change this. I did see that hovering over the table definition it said that an object with this name already exists.